# Remove duplicates from return XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, basex, xquery-3.0

My XQuery is:

```
declare namespace xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"; 
for $schema in xsd:schema
for $nodes in $schema//*,
    $attr in $nodes/xsd:element/@name
where fn:contains($attr,'city')
return $attr
```

return:  `name="city" name="city" name="city" name="city" name="city"`

When I add distinct-values like:

```
declare namespace xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"; 
for $schema in xsd:schema
for $nodes in $schema//*,
    $attr in $nodes/xsd:element/@name
where fn:contains($attr,'city')
return distinct-values($attr)
```

return: `city city city city city`

I need only one "city", how can I do it ?

Comment: Could you post an example of a document you're querying?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to apply the `distinct-values` function on the whole result (i. e., not to each single result item):

```
declare namespace xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"; 
distinct-values(
  for $schema in xsd:schema
  for $nodes in $schema//*,
      $attr in $nodes/xsd:element/@name
  where fn:contains($attr,'city')
  return $attr
)
```

The query can also be written as a single XPath expression:

```
distinct-values(//xs:element/@name[contains(., 'city')])
```

Comment: is there a way to speed this up a bit? I am facing the problem that baseX is pretty slow when using _distinct-values()_ or the _group by_ statement. without, the xquery is finished correctly in 4s. with elimination of double values, however, it takes about 4 minutes. the values are about 60.000 text nodes; each contains a lemma. 1G memory is available for each queries. the only way of speeding this up right now is the work-around to let another language remove the double values...now what I want, actually

Comment: In invite you to send this to the BaseX mailing list, and add further information on your use case, the specific query, etc.

Comment: thanks, I already joined the list. As for the problem mentioned above, I found out that there is a huge difference between case-sensitive and case-insensitive grouping: the latter is slow. So my *solution* was to use the default collation instead of my previously used "html-ascii-case-insensitive"

Answer (score 4):

Use `group by`. Your query returns multiple times `city`, because in each iteration (of the for loop) there is only one such element in `$attr`. So you are doing the `distinct-values` on a single element, but you are doing this multiple times.

```
declare namespace xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"; 
for $schema in xsd:schema
for $nodes in $schema//*,
    $attr in $nodes/xsd:element/@name
where fn:contains($attr,'city')
group by $attr
return $attr
```

Answer (score 0):

This work

```
distinct-values(for $schema in xsd:schema
for $nodes in $schema//*,
    $attr in $nodes/xsd:element/@name
where fn:contains($attr,'city')
return distinct-values($attr))
```