# delete duplicate entities from BaseX with a primary key

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xquery, basex, flwor

How do I remove duplicate entries?

In this case, Twitter uses snowflake's as a unique ID field in the `JSON` for the tweet, which is reflected below.  Build an [index](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Indexes) of tweets, by ID, and delete each additional `$tweet` which has a duplicate?  But how to not end up deleting every single tweet recursively...?

A [simple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60050240/262852) `FLWOR` to print the ID for each tweet in the database:

```
for $tweets  in db:open("twitter")
return <tweet>{$tweets/json/id__str}</tweet>
```

results:

```
thufir@dur:~/flwor/twitter$ 
thufir@dur:~/flwor/twitter$ basex tweetID.xq 
<tweet>
  <id__str>1224165280068382720</id__str>
</tweet>
<tweet>
  <id__str>1224160851797643264</id__str>
</tweet>
<tweet>
  <id__str>1224134565280862208</id__str>
</tweet>
...
<tweet>
  <id__str>1224016596634603520</id__str>
</tweet>
<tweet>
  <id__str>1224001430417297410</id__str>
</tweet>
<tweet>
  <id__str>1223987662094249991</id__str>
</tweet>thufir@dur:~/flwor/twitter$ 
thufir@dur:~/flwor/twitter$
```

The duplicates here are intentional, but looking for some way to "clean up" the database.

Just looking for a general outline or approach.  My thinking is to pipe output from one `xquery` into another, but am stuck at how to build an index.  Presumably this is a [functionality built into the database itself](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Indexes), just need to leverage the correct module ([probably](https://mailman.uni-konstanz.de/pipermail/basex-talk/2011-July/001823.html)).

--

this looks to return a [different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16873753/262852) result, at least:

```
distinct-values(
    for $tweets in db:open("twitter") 
    return ($tweets/json/id__str))
```

although I'm not quite sure it's the set of all `id__str` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and tested two approaches that were already discussed here. Both approaches can be used to delete duplicates but there are performance differences.

1. The `distinct-values` approach:

   ```
   (: Open database :)
   let $db := db:open('db-name')

   (: Get all distinct IDs :)
   let $ids := distinct-values($db/record/id)

   for $id in $ids
     (: Get all records with the same ID :)
     let $recsWithSameId := data($db/record/id)=$id

     (: Return only duplicate records :)
     return if (count($recsWithSameId)>1) then
       $recsWithSameId

       (: Instead of returning the duplicate records you can now delete all records except the one you want to keep. Then you removed the duplicates. :)
   ```
2. The `group by` approach:

   ```
   for $recs in db:open('db-name')/record
     let $id := $recs/id
     group by $id
     return
       if (count($recs) > 1) then      
         $recs
         (: Instead of returning the duplicate records you can now delete all records except the one you want to keep. Then you removed the duplicates. :)
   ```

The second approach (`group by`) is much faster than the first one (`distinct-values`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use group by in a FLOWR to get duplicates. It should also be faster than `distinct()`.

```
for $tweets  in db:open("twitter")
let $id := $tweets/json/id__str
group by $id
return
  if (count($tweets) > 1)
  then (for-each(tail($tweets), function ($tweet) { (: remove $tweet from DB :) } ) 
  else () (: nothing to do :)
```

Comment: what is `function ($t)`?

Comment: `$t` was short for `$tweet`. I made the code example a little more clear.